# Interface Gráfica com JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estou começando a estudar JavaFx no curso livre de java que peguei na Udemy. Como sou novo em java, gostaria de entender qual a vantagem de trabalhar com essa biblioteca se comparado a desenvolver uma interface web. Além disso tenho a impressão de JavaFx ser uma biblioteca antiga, ela ainda seria uma boa opção se comparada com outras opções de bibliotecas de interface gráfica?

Existe outra opção de biblioteca para trabalhar com interface gráfica em java que em quesitos de atualidade e complexidade, seja melhor que JavaFX?

Desde já agradeço a todos.